# A loop to manipulate a WORD in C

Tags: c, windows, loops, motorola

i'm trying to write down an algorithm in C which should manipulate an hipotetical WORD.

Let's say we've got a WORD like this:

```
WORD testStart = 0x000;
```

Now i need to increment values to reach 0xFFF. But I need to increment the last byte from 00 to FF, and the first nibble from 0 to F.

Is there a way to achieve that result?

I'm not very skilled in C and I've noticed that as per integers I can use the "++" operator, but if I do:

```
test+=125;
```

It doesn't work properly...

Recapping:

```
WORD testStart,testEnd;

testStart = 0x000;
testEnd = 0xFFF;

while(1){
             if(testStart < testEnd ){ 
                     if(testStart%25==0)
                     testStart+=0x7D; //If byte is multiple of 25 I want to add 1 to the nibble value 
                     else
                     testStart++;  //else just add 1 to byte
             }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I sense some incompleteness in your question. Why can't you use `test = test + 1`, and why can you only increase per nibble/byte?

Comment: .. why and how did you come up with `125`? If you use the value `273` instead, you will see it adds up to the target `0x0FFF` in only 15 steps. Print out the intermediate values in hex to see why.

Comment: With the number 125 i was trying to increase the nibble AND the last byte.

Comment: Well if you check its hex value (`0x007D`), you can easily see why it would not work. Are you confusing hex and decimal notation? (Hence my suggested magic value and the hint to check the result in *hex*...)

Comment: `WORD` is not standard C99, it looks like something specific to Windows. So you should tag your question as *Windows*; POSIX systems don't use `WORD` (but C99 has `<stdint.h>` with `intptr_t`...)

Comment: I've edited as suggested. the +=0x7D operator is rightly spelled? another thing...the modulus is right too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break that WORD into two variables, let's say:

```
WORD x = 0xFF;
WORD y = 0xF;
```

and then construct the result by writing:

```
WORD z;
z = x + (y << 8);
```

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for this:

```
WORD testStart, testEnd, byte, nibble; //replace with names of your liking

testEnd = 0xFFF;
byte = 0x00;
nibble = 0x0;


while(1){
             testStart = byte + (nibble << 8);
             if(testStart < testEnd )
             { 
                     if(byte == 0xFF)
                     {
                       nibble++;
                     }
                     else //byte is not 0xFF
                     {
                       byte++;
                     } 
             }

}
```

Comment: Interesting...but can u explain why need 8 byteshift to obtain the linked work in the join example?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do the following :

```
WORD testStart,testEnd;

testStart = 0x000;
testEnd = 0xFFF;

while(testStart != testEnd) testStart++;
```